# Why does the 'layout_column' does not place the element in a GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have the following example xml layout, taken from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) (removed some unimportant parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:columnCount="4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Email setup"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Email address:"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <EditText
        android:ems="10"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Password:"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <EditText
        android:ems="8"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

I am changing the parameter for `android:layout_column` for the 'Next'-button in the last line from 3 to 2, but this does not change it's position on the layout:

[image: Next button position]

In my understanding in a Grid-Layout I have several columns, and the parameter `layout_column` specifies the column in which to place the element. But this does not seem to work. The element's position does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first column ends on the right of `Password` (at least it's `android:layout_column="0"` indicates that)

This is also the start of column 1. But you have not specified any element in this column. So it spans the rest of the width of `GridLayout`.

It would be better to set column span only to 2, and set button's span to 2 with `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:text="Email setup"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Email address:"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:ems="10"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Password:"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:ems="8"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I see. And  the first EditText box defines the right location of column 2 (or left location of column 3), which places the textbox somewhat 'outside' of the screen?

Comment: Exactly EditText box defines the start location of Button outside of screen as all textboxes are visible. But I think you get the point.

Comment: Yes, I think I have learned something today. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You must set `android:columnOrderPreserved="false"` to get this work.Then changing `layout_column` will work